# Как получить все транзакции карты сбера?

Tags: веб-программирование, api

Хочу сделать оплату на сайте, но перевод будет в ручном режиме. То есть, человек отправляет деньги на карту которая указана на сайте и потом проверять перевод от человека по комментарию. Есть ли в API сбера такая штука, чтобы получить все переводы на мою карту? В инете и в их нем апи ничего не нашел. Физ лицо

Comment: Для физиков - не думаю. Да и для юриков врят ли. Возможно есть система выставления счетов и их оплаты онлайн для самозанятых, но это уже другая история.